# How do I open a JarFile for reading without encountering a ZipException?

Tags: java, jar

I have been programming Java for around 15 years.  While this is a basic question, it is not due to willful ignorance of the Java APIs or of reading the documentation.  To be frank, I am really alarmed that I have encountered a situation where *I cannot create a simple jar file with command line tools and open it using the `java.util.jar.*` API.*  My detailed step-by-step process is below.

I have used `jar -cf` to create a simple `.jar` file for testing.  It contains one text file in it.  Here is the output from my shell showing how I created it in my Maven project's `src/test/resources` directory:

```
Laird-Nelsons-MacBook-Pro:resources ljnelson$ cat > a.txt
Hello!
Laird-Nelsons-MacBook-Pro:resources ljnelson$ jar cf source.jar .
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Laird-Nelsons-MacBook-Pro:resources ljnelson$ ls -al
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 ljnelson  staff  136 Dec 28 13:21 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 ljnelson  staff  136 Dec 28 13:01 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 ljnelson  staff    7 Dec 28 13:21 a.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 ljnelson  staff  445 Dec 28 13:21 source.jar
Laird-Nelsons-MacBook-Pro:resources ljnelson$ jar tf source.jar 
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
a.txt
```

(The `Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` is to work around a Mac bug where the default file encoding on the terminal is `MacRoman`.  You need to manually set the file encoding to `UTF-8` if you want to see accurately represented Unicode characters on your screen.  To my knowledge, this has nothing to do with the problem I'm seeing.)

Then the following test case code fails when the `JarFile` is created:

```
public File getSourceJarFile() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
  final URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/source.jar");
  assertNotNull(url);
  final URI uri = url.toURI();
  assertNotNull(uri);
  final String path = uri.getPath();
  assertNotNull(path);
  return new File(path);
}

@Test
public void testWTF() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
  final File file = this.getSourceJarFile();
  assertNotNull(file);
  assertTrue(file.isFile());
  assertTrue(file.canRead());
  // At this point, the file itself is there and can be read by this user.
  JarFile jarFile = null;
  try {
    jarFile = new JarFile(file); // XXX KABOOM
  } finally {
    if (jarFile != null) {
      jarFile.close();
    }
  }
}
```

The exception is:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:127)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:135)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:99)
at com.foobar.TestCaseJarFileWTF.testWTF(TestCaseJarFileWTF.java:72)
```

To recap:

- I create a `source.jar` file in a place that is accessible to my test case using the simplest invocation of the `jar` command line tool.
- I verify that this file actually exists, both visually and in my test case.
- I have opened this file successfully in `emacs`, with `jar -xf`, and with `unzip`.  It is a valid jar and zip file.
- I confirm in my test case that it can be read by the currently running user.

I feel stupid admitting this, but I guess I must have not even the most basic of understanding as to how the `JarFile` constructor works.  Any input here is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried accessing it as a file instead as of a classpath resource?

Comment: As you can see, the File that I get my hands on exists and is readable.

Comment: that wasn't my question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven strikes again.  I had the test resources area set up for [Maven filtering](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-filtering/) so the resulting zip file had probably had its innards scrambled.  I hope my failure here helps others to troubleshoot similar problems.